# Mapbox GL checkbox menu

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, context-menu

I am trying to toggle layers and legends using a checkbox menu. I'm able to toggle the bathroom and sq ft legends, but I'm not sure how to identify the layer layout in order to toggle it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    // add mapbox links and style the map
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Laughlin Housing Variance</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.33.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.33.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<!-- identify the map -->
<div id='map'></div>
<!-- identify one legend for each of 3 variances -->
<div id='Bed-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Colors By Bedroom Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #4575b4'></span>Yardi lower in beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #54278f'></span>Yardi equals Plan</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi higher by 1 beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #f768a1'></span>Yardi higher by 2 beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #7a0177'></span>Yardi higher by 3+ beds</div>
</div>
<div id='Bath-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Colors By Bathroom Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #4575b4'></span>Yardi lower in baths</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #54278f'></span>Yardi equals Plan</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi higher by 0.5 baths</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #f768a1'></span>Yardi higher by 1 bath</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #7a0177'></span>Yardi higher by 2+ baths</div>
</div>
<div id='Sqft-legend' class='legend' style='display: visible;'>
    <h4>Colors By Sq Ft Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #0c2c84'></span>Yardi lower: 644 - 858</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fd8d3c'></span>Yardi lower: 431 - 644</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #c6dbef'></span>Yardi lower: 50 - 431</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi equals Plan (+ or - 50)</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #41ab5d'></span>Yardi higher by > 50 </div>
</div>
<div id='menu'>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Laughlin Homes by Variance Type:</legend>
    <input id='Bed' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Bedroom' >
    <label for='Bed'>bedrooms</label>
    <input id='Bath' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Bathroom' >
    <label for='Bath'>bathrooms</label>
    <input id='Sq_Ft' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Sq_Feet' checked='checked'>
    <label for='Sq_Ft'>square feet</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGtheW5lMjMiLCJhIjoiN2ZuVll5MCJ9.INSHe8gm7HMfO8HZPUuAhg';


var rtoggle = 'Sq_Ft' // It's the checked radio selection
var zoomThreshold = 15;
var choropleths = {};
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    // use any style; this is a predefined mapbox style
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10',
    center: [-100.784, 29.351],
    zoom: 14.2
});

// add navigational control
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');

// define variables
var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');
var bedLegendEl = document.getElementById('Bed-legend');
var bathLegendEl = document.getElementById('Bath-legend');
var sqftLegendEl = document.getElementById('Sqft-legend');

// define functions
function switchLayer(layer) {
    var layerId = layer.target.id;
    // set layer id to a menu value
    // If id = Bed
       if (layerId == 'Bed') {
          map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom.layout', 'visibility', 'visible');
          map.setLayoutProperty('Bathroom.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
          map.setLayoutProperty('Sq_Feet.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
          bedLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
          bathLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
          sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
        }
        // If id = Bath
       if (layerId == 'Bath') {
         map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
         map.setLayoutProperty('Bathroom.layout', 'visibility', 'visible');
         map.setLayoutProperty('Sq_Feet.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
         bedLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
         bathLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
         sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
        }
       // Else id = Sq_Ft
       else {
         map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
         map.setLayoutProperty('Bathroom.layout', 'visibility', 'none');
         map.setLayoutProperty('Sq_Feet.layout', 'visibility', 'visible');
        bedLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
        bathLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
        sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
       }
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
}

// do this before any menu events
map.on('load', function () {
    // source is a TMK tileset; same source for all layers
    map.addSource('laughlincombined4326', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://tkayne23.7gg2xn4y'
    });

    // add variance by bedrooms to paint units
    // can be controlled by either the filter or visibility option
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'Bedroom',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
        'layout': {'visibility': 'none'},
        'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
        //'filter': ['==', document.getElementById('Bed_Varian').checked, true],
        'paint': {
              'fill-color': {
              'property': 'Bed_Varian',
              'type': 'interval',
              'stops': [
                    [-5, '#4575b4'],
                    [0, '#54278f'],
                    [1, '#fcc5c0'],
                    [2, '#f768a1'],
                    [3, '#7a0177']
                  ]
               },
              'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
              'fill-opacity': 0.9
            }
        },);


      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'Bathroom',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
        'layout': {'visibility': 'none'},
        'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
        //'filter': ['==', document.getElementById('Bath_Varia').checked, true],
        'paint': {
              'fill-color': {
              'property': 'Bath_Varia',
              'type': 'interval',
              'stops': [
                    [-5, '#4575b4'],
                    [0, '#54278f'],
                    [.5, '#fcc5c0'],
                    [1, '#f768a1'],
                    [2, '#7a0177']
                  ]
               },
              'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
              'fill-opacity': 0.9
            }
        },);


        map.addLayer({
        'id': 'Sq_Feet',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
        //'maxzoom': zoomThreshold,
        'layout': {'visibility': 'visible'},
        'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
        //'filter': ['==', document.getElementById('Sq_Ft_Vari').checked, true],
        'paint': {
              'fill-color': {
              'property': 'Sq_Ft_Vari',
              'type': 'interval',
              'stops': [
                    [-858, '#0c2c84'],
                    [-654, '#fd8d3c'],
                    [-431, '#c6dbef'],
                    [-50, '#fcc5c0'],
                    [50, '#41ab5d']
                  ]
               },
              'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
              'fill-opacity': 0.9
            }
        },);


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi tkayne,I tried your code,just remove the layout from your code because you already using setLayoutProperty so your code line this  map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom', 'visibility', 'none'); It works for me thanks.

Comment: @SeemaBarate you should post your comment as an answer